# Need to update product price through Csv through Sku code

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

So i need to update price of multiple product the record of which i have got in excel . I have sku code of the product and their updated prices .

I know i can update the prices by finding each product from the backend and updating them one by one , but that takes a lot of time and seems kind of impractical if i have hundreds of product to update .

Does anyone have a script or way , so that i can update the prices at once using the products sku code to find them and update the price with the price provided in the excel sheet.

Comment: Don't you know how to import product csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your csv file as shown in below image.

[image]

Now navigate to

> System >> Import

Choose **Products** in `Entity Type` and **Add/Update** in `Import Behaviour`.